# How to make a scatter plot from unique values of df column against index where they first appear?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, uniqueidentifier

I have a data frame df with the shape (100, 1)

```py
     point
    0 1
    1 12
    2 13
    3 1
    4 1
    5 12
    ...
```

I need to make a scatter plot of unique values from column 'point'.

I tried to drop duplicates and move indexes of unique values to a column called 'indeks', and then to plot:

```py
    uniques = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    uniques.loc['indeks'] = uniques.index
```

and I get:

```py
    ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Is there a smart way to plot only unique values where they first appear?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with no parameter if need only first unique values and remove `.loc` for new column:

```
uniques = df.drop_duplicates().copy()
uniques['indeks'] = uniques.index 
print (uniques)
   point  indeks
0      1       0
1     12       1
2     13       2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to just substitute duplicates with NaN?

Comment: @Rosa - then use `df['point'] = df['point'].mask(df.duplicated())`